# Metamask doesn't work when sending EIP-681 transactions

Tags: erc-20, metamask, eip, eip681

I use this website to create EIP-681 transactions:
https://brunobar79.github.io/eip681-link-generator/#

My default wallet is Metamask. When I scan the QR code for the transaction and proceed it, it fails:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xbcad631b6ef04914802b1f1f320239a4a96ad68dae52ac666b76f0e69f8b30c2

If I do it manually, select the ERC20 token in my metamask and transfer 1 token to the same address as above, it works:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x686695adeb1698df3517f18a5a3d3742c994b5f267a6278307e98c3f14e6ee74

Can someone explain me what might be happening? I would like to add that all was working fine last 2 weeks, but since yesterday when I try to attempt the first execution with the QR code it fails. I can`t understand why was it working and suddenly it stopped. I tried adjusting the gas, it did not help me.